# I need to get the max from a Employee class from a Farm class

Tags: java

I need to find and display the the employee who has the maximum salary from the Farm.
 this is what I got so far

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
private String name;
private Integer salary;

public Employee (String name , Integer salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
public Integer getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public String toString() {
    return name + " " + salary;
}
public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
    return this.salary.compareTo(emp.getSalary());
}
```

}

Employee class

```
public class Farm {
private String name;
private Integer surface;

List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();


public Farm(String name , Integer surface) {
    this.name =  name;
    this.surface = surface;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;

}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setSurface(Integer surface) {
    this.surface = surface;
}
public int getSurface () {
    return surface;
}
public String toString() {
    return name + " " + surface;
}
public void makeList(String ename , Integer esalary) {
    this.emp.add(new Employee(ename,esalary));
}
public void getList() {
    for(Employee el : emp)
        System.out.println(el);
}
```

}

And the last one is the main. The thing is that I don't know how can I have more farms and get the max from every single one of them. Can you guys help me?

And this is my mainapp

```
public class Mainapp {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    List <Farm> FarmList = new ArrayList<Farm>();
    FarmList.add(new Farm("unirea pizdii", 890030));
    FarmList.add(new Farm("pseudo autsm",78594));
    FarmList.add(new Farm("haha hihi",854856099));

    Farm farm1 = new Farm("Tiguana" , 700);
    farm1.makeList("Mihai", 30000);
    farm1.makeList("Vladimir", 4000);
    farm1.makeList("Tusnic", 3000);
    farm1.getList();


    Employee emp1 =  new Employee(" mihai", 3000);
    System.out.println(emp1);
}
```

}

Comment: Add a maxSalary method to farm that loops over the `emp` list and compares salaries and then returns the employee with the highest salary. Then you can call this method for every farm you have.

Comment: Your `compareTo()` violates the contract to be consistent with `equals` and `hashCode`, which you don't even override. What you need is a separate `Comparator` subtype to relate salaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get employee with max salary for each farm you can use stream api:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<Farm, Optional<Employee>> collect = 
        farmList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),
            flatMapping(farm -> farm.getEmployes().stream(), 
                   maxBy(Employee::compareTo))));
```

Result map has `Farm` as a key and `Employee` with max salary as a value

Note: `flatMapping` method is from java9

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to sort a List in Java, one of them being [`Collections.sort(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-), but in this case it looks like you are trying to retrieve the maximum value from the list, so there's no need to add the extra overhead.

> **EDIT:** [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) suggested using [`Collections.max(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-):
>
> ```java
> public Employee getMostPaidEmployee() {
>   return Collections.max(emp);
> }
> ```

One way to get the most paid employee from the list would be to loop through them and compare each one to the previously "saved" most paid employee:

```java
// Farm.java
public Employee getMostPaidEmployee() {
  Employee mostPaid = null;

  // Initialize maximum to the lowest possible value.
  // If salaries can only be positive you could also initialize this to `0`.
  int maximumSalary = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

  for (Employee employee : emp) {
    if (employee.getSalary() > maximumSalary) {
      // Reset the most paid fields
      mostPaid = employee;
      maximumSalary = employee.getSalary();
    }
  }

  return mostPaid;
}
```

You can declare this method on the `Farm` class, so you will be able to call it even if you have multiple instances of `Farm`:

```java
List<Farm> farms = new ArrayList<>();

// TODO Add farms

// Get the most paid employee in first farm
Employee mostPaid = farms.get(0).getMostPaidEmployee();
```

In terms of performance, this method is linear, i.e. `O(n)`.

Comment: nice answer, don't forget to specify the return type in the method signature though. `public Employee getMostPaidEmployee()`

Comment: So this method I should put it in the Farm class and get the Most paid employee.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed, wrote the answer quickly and didn't check for code issues 

Comment: Why not read the remaining of the Collections class javadoc, and then use Collections.max() (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-)?

Comment: Ok guys I got another think that gets me <Create a map from the farm list wich has like key the salary and like value the list of employee that has that salary. Display the map content, and for each employee display the farm in wich is working >  Can I get some help with this ?